# jQuery Syntax error, unrecognized expression error when Tag id contains `$` sign

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to hide a specific `div` element, the name of which contains `$` sign, but I get the following error in firebug:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $Frame
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Button1").click(function() {
    $("#ctl00_content_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_PdEnd$Frame").hide();
})
```

What's wrong??

Comment: as i know, $ will append in name property, not in the id property. you check it once.

Comment: I checked it. it's in id property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "$" is legitimate in your selector string you need to use selector special character escape rules

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Try:

```
 $("#ctl00_content_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_PdEnd\\$Frame").hide();
```

I don't do a lot in asp but that "$" sure looks supicious

Comment: This also worked for me to escape the [ and ] characters. I was trying to do the following and it worked in jQuery 1.3.2 but did not work when I upgraded to 1.7.2:

Did not work: $("input[name=circumstances[]]:checked").val()

Did work: $("input[name=circumstances\\\[\\\]]:checked").val()

Answer (score 2):

I checked and jquery is not working may be use native javascript as workaround.

```
document.getElementById('h$ello');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with 'j'
j(document).ready(function() {
        j("#Button1").click(function() {
           j("#ctl00_content_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_PdEnd$Frame").hide();
        });    
});
```

Comment: But the problem dollar-sign is in the selector (string) - this isn't a conflict issue.